# ffmpeg combine images and audio into video and loop through images until end of audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I have found this code to combine multiple images and one audio file into video, but what I want is the images to loop until the end of audio. So what I mean, if I have 5 images and each image is shown for 5 seconds, after 25 seconds show again the first image, second image etc and this will continue until the end of audio.

```
ffmpeg -r 0.2 -i Scan-130802-%04d.jpg -i "1.mp3" \
       -vcodec libx264 -vf scale=1920:1080 \
       -crf 25 -preset slow -acodec copy video.mp4
```

another problem I have is that with the above code the images appear horizontally flipped for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more efficient to do this in two steps.

#1

`ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i Scan-130802-%04d.jpg -vf "scale=1920:1080,setsar=1" -r 5 -c:v libx264 -crf 25 -preset slow scan-video.mp4`

#2

`ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i scan-video.mp4 -i "1.mp3" -codec copy -shortest -fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 200M video.mp4`